# If f and g are monotone functions, such that f is continuous and f(x)=g(x) for rationals x, then g is also continuous

Tags: real-analysis

Let f and g be monotone functions on R such that f is continuous and g(x) = f(x) for all rational numbers x, then g is also continuous on R.

My idea is a such:

Without loss of generality, we assume that f is monotone increasing. 
Since g = f for all rational numbers, g is monotone increasing for all rational numbers as well.

Suppose g is not continuous, then the limit of these two sequence are different.

By the density of real numbers, we can find a sequence of rational numbers that tend to c and a sequence of irrational numbers that tend to the same c.

Since the limit of these two sequences are different, they must differ by an amount say M.

However, again by the density of real numbers, there exists rational numbers and irrational numbers within this interval M. Hence, contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Let $c\in\mathbb{R}$.

Since $\mathbb Q$ is dense we can construct a sequences
$\left(x_{n}\right)$ and $\left(y_{n}\right)$ in $\mathbb Q$ both converging
to $c$ and with $x_{n}<c<y_{n}$.

Then $f\left(x_{n}\right)=g\left(x_{n}\right)\leq g\left(c\right)\leq g\left(y_{n}\right)=f\left(y_{n}\right)$
or $f\left(x_{n}\right)=g\left(x_{n}\right)\geq g\left(c\right)\geq g\left(y_{n}\right)=f\left(y_{n}\right)$
because $g$ is monotone.

This combined with $f\left(x_{n}\right)\rightarrow f\left(c\right)$
and $f\left(y_{n}\right)\rightarrow f\left(c\right)$ leads to $f\left(c\right)=g\left(c\right)$.

Proved is now that $f$ and $g$ coincide on $\mathbb{R}$ so that
$g$ is continuous like $f$.